# SPA thin or thick architecture

Tags: design, design-patterns, architectural-patterns

I seek your advice on SPA ([Single-page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_page_application)) architecture.

I'm building an SPA which edits a model. The models consists of objects which have a relation to one another. The objects (and relations) are stored in a single a collection on the server's database. The user must authenticate on server and sessions are implemented to track user activities.

For this SPA I have a choice in thick or thin serve architecture.

**SPA thin server architecture**

The complexity of managing inter object relations (model) is done on the client

Full data set is exchanged between client and server and there

Few interactions between client and server

Heartbeat pattern is implemented to keep session alive after authentication

Process:

User logs in (heartbeat starts)

Client fetches all objects from the server database collection

Client constructs a data model from the objects (using the relations) and visualizes the model

User edits the model and saves the changes

On save the client deconstructs the data model

All objects are submitted to the server which stores these 1:1 in the database collection

**SPA thick server architecture**

The complexity of managing inter object relations (model) is done on the server

Small data packages are exchanged between client and server (after initial load)

Many interactions between client and server

Frequent changes omit the need for heartbeat to keep the session alive
(though I except the risk of a session will time-out due to prolonged inactivity of the user)

Process:

User logs in

Client fetches all objects from the server database collection

Client visualizes the server side model *but does not construct a client side data model*

User edits the visualized model where each change is submitted to the sever

Servers logic determines the changes to the model and updates (1 or more) the collection accordingly

Which architecture would be favored for my SPA - and why?

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503991/spa-architecture - your question is actually on topic for here and has been closed on SO